# Extracting numbers from string in R using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this:

```
myString <- "[0.15][4577896]blahblahblahblahwhatever"
```

I need to extract the number between second brackets.

Currently I am trying to use this:

```
str_extract(myString, "\\]\\[(\\d+)")
```

But this gives me `][4577896`

My desired result would be: `4577896`

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Use [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html): `stringr::str_extract(myString, "(?<=\\]\\[)(\\d+)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this .`(?<=\]\[)(\d+)`

This is a demo.https://regex101.com/r/fvHW05/1

Answer (score 3):

With no need of look behinds

```
gsub(".*\\[(\\d+).*","\\1",myString)
[1] "4577896"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version with minimal or no regex

```
qdapRegex::ex_between_multiple(myString, "[", "]")[[2]]
#[1] "4577896"
```

It extracts all the substring between `[` and `]` and we select the value between second bracket. You can convert it into numeric or integer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?:[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]+\])[^\]\[]*\[([^\]\[]+).+
```

And replace this with the first captured group using `gsub`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7fBM9v/1/).
In base `R`:

```
myString <- "[0.15][4577896]blahblahblahblahwhatever"

pattern <- "^(?:[^\\[\\]]*\\[[^\\[\\]]+\\])[^\\]\\[]*\\[([^\\]\\[]+).+"
gsub(pattern, "\\1", myString, perl = T)
# [1] "4577896"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(myString, "(?<=.\\[)([0-9]+)")
#[1] "4577896"
```